# Does nginx read all the files in the folder /etc/nginx/sites-available/

Tags: nginx

I have renamed the **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** to **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default.bak**. Is it okay to leave the default.bak file in the sites-available folder. Will the nginx read the configurations in the default.bak file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely up to how you configure NGinx.  Typically, there is a directive in `/etc/nginx.conf` (or where ever your configuration file is):

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

This would load all files that match the pattern.  You could adjust to be something else.  However, typically, it is set up so that `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` contains links to some or all of the configurations in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` which would allow you to easily enable or disable sites.